# How do I loop an array through an iframe with javascript (like php foreach)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So what I would like to do is loop these embed codes into the iframe. By that I mean I would like to loop all embed codes and iframes over and over so that all 3 iframes would show. Exactly like a Php foreach loop.

```
var cars = [
    "//www.youtube.com/embed/NcjgvcyQ41c",
    "//www.youtube.com/embed/NcjgvcyQ41c",
    "//www.youtube.com/embed/NcjgvcyQ41c"
];
for (var i in cars) {
  output += ("<iframe width="560" height="315" src="cars[i]" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>"); 

}
```

Incase you don't get what I mean. 
when the file runs, I want to show -->
--IFRAME--
--IFRAME--
--IFRAME--

So that all the embed codes will show up as iframes! :) Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

without jquery there is no foreach loop. you'd need to do a for loop like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++){
 output += ("<iframe width="560" height="315" src="cars[i]" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen><     </iframe>"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript (today) the `for` loop is not terribly useful.

For an array, it enumerates the indices of the array:

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (var i : a)
    console.log(i);

> 0
> 1
> 2
```

For an object, it enumerates the keys.

```
var a = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
for (var i : a)
    console.log(i);

> a
> b
> c
```

Given this, you should use a `for (;;)` loop instead of a `for (... in ...)` loop.

Comment: Well, then you just use the keys to access the data as a[i]. That even works with object keys. The real danger here is that it loops properties from the prototype as well. Because of this, a check with a.hasOwnProperty(i) is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/1wLuxy3w/

Take the array, and use a for loop instead

```
for( var i=0; i<cars.length; i++ )
{
    output += 'your iframe here';
}
```

Also, your use of quotes was wrong. Make sure the quotes wrapping the entire string are different from the ones being used within the string, or at least escape the contained quotes with a backslash.

Then you want to add the concatenated output to an element in the DOM

```
elem = document.getElementById("#yourElement");
elem.innerHTML = output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a foreach loop like php it wasn't in the language until es5 though so it's not supported by all browsers, it won't work in ie 8 and lower. You'd be better of using a for loop in this case. Here's the foreach anyway.

```
cars.forEach(function(value){

    output += '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' + value + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

});
```

[forEach documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Look at this [es 5 compatibility](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/) table. Check the Show obsolete browsers? checkbox up top

The quotes around the attribute values are ending the string early use single quotes to enclose the string instead.